# Font don't work on browsers, except Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

So, I'm trying to put [this font](http://www.dafont.com/isl-fade-to-blak.font) on my page, but it doesn't work on Firefox, IE, and Opera, only on Chrome. (didn't try Safari)
Is there a way to make it work?

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ISL Fade to Blak';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("Fonts/ftb.ttf") format("truetype");
}
.perg_text {
    font-family: 'ISL Fade to Blak';
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Since members are asking, yes, I'm declaring the font-family on the body.

HTML:

```
<div class="perg_text">TEXT HERE</div>
```

Comment: https://www.fonts.com/support/faq/web-fonts-work-only-in-firefox

This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: why are you using a `ttf` source instead of a WOFF? Also, where is the CSS that shows how you're actually using that newly declared font family?

Comment: Hi! First, thanks for your awnsers. Yes, I'm declaring the font on the body, and other custom fonts works perfectly on all browsers, except this one that works only on Chrome. About the domain, I don't think that's the case, since other fonts are working. About WOFF type, the site that I downloaded the font only disponibilizes ttf file. I tryied to convert the font on sites that do that, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`@font-face` is just for declaring a font. You should show that you are using that font. You must be add this to your css.

```
body {
  font-family: 'ISL Fade to Blak';
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it would be necessary to say, since it's workin on Chrome, but yes, I'm declaring the font-family on the body. I'm using other fonts to, and those work on every browser, except this one that works only on Chrome. Thanks.